# Recaptcha Missing required parameters: sitekey

Tags: reactjs, invisible-recaptcha

I'm integrating recaptcha to my react app and I'm having this error: "Missing required parameters: sitekey" when I use the render method of grecaptch even though I have properly included the sitekey in to the parameters.

Here is my code for reference:

```
class ReCaptcha extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    this.callbackName = 'g-lf-callback';
    window[this.callbackName] = this.props.callback;

    if(window.grecaptcha) {

        this.renderRecaptcha();
    } else {

        this.loadRecaptchaScript();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

    delete window['rconload'];
    delete window[this.callbackName];
  }

  loadRecaptchaScript() {

    window['rconload'] = () => {

        this.renderRecaptcha();
    };

    let url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=rconload&render=explicit';
    loadScript(url, '', 'recaptcha', true, true)
    .then( () => {})
    .catch( () => {});
  }

  renderRecaptcha = () => {

    if(this.container) {

        let parameters = {
            sitekey: process.env.MY_SITEKEY,
            size: 'invisible',
            badge: null,
            callback: 'g-lf-callback'
        };

        const recaptchaId = window.grecaptcha.render(this.container, parameters);

        this.execute = () => window.grecaptcha.execute(recaptchaId);
        this.reset = () => window.grecaptcha.reset(recaptchaId);
        this.getResponse = () => window.grecaptcha.getResponse(recaptchaId);
    }

  }

  onClick = () => {

    this.execute();
  }

  render() {

    let { callback, label, className, ...btnProps } = this.props;

    return (
        <Button
            { ...btnProps }
            className={ className }
            onClick={ this.onClick }
            ref = { ref => this.container = ref }
        >
            { label }
        </Button>
    )
  }
}
```

I have also set the render parameter of recaptcha url to explicit

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=rconload&render=explicit
```

Onload callback:

```
window['rconload'] = () => {

    this.renderRecaptcha();
};
```

Comment: Should this: `'sitekey': 'recaptcha_sitekey',` be: `'sitekey': recaptcha_sitekey,`?

Comment: I'm just replacing the actual sitekey string with 'recaptcha_sitekey'

Comment: Can you show all your code / where you actually fill the key?

Comment: The sitekey is retrieved from the env file. I tried to verify the returned value from env and it seems it's returning it properly.

Comment: Can you show all your code please.

Comment: Updated the description.

Comment: What is `loadScript()`?

Comment: It's a method I created to insert an external script like reCaptcha's.

Comment: Why arent you using a built in component that already has the integration, something like: `react-google-recaptcha`?

Comment: I'm trying to create one myself.